# Grub dual boot results in windows error code 0x000428

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

For some reason I am getting an error when trying to boot into windows boot manager. The error code is 0x000428 Windows cannot verify digital signature. I know it is not an issue with the windows boot loader because if boot strait to the windows boot loader I don't get any errors and it boots right up. This only happens when I boot into grub and then select the Windows Boot Manger selection. So I can only assume this is an issue with grub. So I don't know if maybe grub caches these values somewhere or if there is some kind of issue in a grub config somewhere. It was working fine and then it just wasn't. Not sure when it broke because I don't boot into windows that often.

I first thought it was a windows issue so I reinstalled windows but that didn't matter. I have tried using boot repair to reinstall grub but no luck. Does anyone know what the issue could be? If I can't figure it out my next move will be to just nuke everything and reinstall both ubuntu and windows. I might try to upgrade to the upcoming 23.10.

I am on Ubuntu 23.04

Comment: @user68186 Ya I tried that. Second paragraph of the question.

Comment: Grub did not boot Windows if UEFI Secure boot is on. That may be fixed now. But is Windows fast startup or bitlocker on? Does Windows boot ok when booting directly from UEFI boot menu?

Comment: @oldfred secure boot is off and like I said in the question windows boots just fine if you boot directly into it from the boot menu. There is no fast startup or bitlocker.

Comment: Checked with Google and: "Windows can't verify the digital signature of recent hardware or software. The error code 0xc0000428 may also occur if Windows cannot verify the digital signature of recent hardware or software."  So UEFI Secure Boot is on. Note that Windows update may update UEFI and reset it to defaults. And its update may turn fast startup back on. When boot issue into Windows from grub always double check that settings have not changed.

Comment: @oldfred secure boot and fast startup are not on.

Comment: I have also just run into this problem. Starting the system from the windows boot manager directly gives no problem, but starting it from Grub gives the error. Strange indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently had the same problem because I needed to upgrade some packages with the Mantic (23.10) repository. The problem presented to me with Grub version: `2.12~rc1-4ubuntu3`.

I was able to work around it by adding `rmmod peimage` to the `grub.cfg` entry. Like this:

```
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-8050-6F7A' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod fat
        rmmod peimage
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8050-6F7A
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

For more information please check the bug issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/2030810

Comment: Worked like a charm. So I did end up upgrading to the development version of 23.10 and I checked the grub version and it is the same as you stated above so this fix works for that version but I'm not sure if it would work with the previous version that I had originally because I didn't test it but it works for this version. Thanks.